# Is MongoDB caching queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB as my database for NodeJS system what working heavily with it database.

I am using Mongoose module as database controller.

**My question is:** Is MongoDB or Mongoose somehow caching queries?
I am experiencing problems with fetching data from database.

**What I mean by that?**

When I for for example use aggregate db query in same second and I expect different results, I am getting same result.

It can be caused by my code, but before I start digging into I need to be sure that its not caused by some hidden cashing feature.

Answer (score 5):

The
[FAQ: MongoDB Fundamentals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/)
says this:

> **Does MongoDB handle caching?**
>
> Yes. MongoDB keeps most recently used data in RAM. If you have created
>   indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM,
>   MongoDB serves all queries from memory.
>
> **MongoDB does not cache the query results in order to return the cached results for identical queries.**

However, this does not mean that caching does not occur at all:
If you are reaching the MongoDB server via the Web,
both the browser and the web-server are perfectly capable of caching URLs
and their answer.

In most cases, good web-servers do not cache a URL that looks to be dynamic,
meaning that it includes a question-mark (`?`) with parameter(s) at its end.
You may check the documentation of your web-server, or send a query to its
developers (if accessible), to know if this remedy will work.